# How did I lose a pistol? Pickpocket or saved game bug?

Tags: fallout-2

I'm playing Fallout 2 for the first time, and got my first firearms - a pair of 10mm pistols, with different amounts of bullets in them. I equipped one, topped up its bullets, and left the other in my pack, and removed its bullets. I walked around The Den for a while, and may have swapped an item or two in my hands, and saved my game, and stopped playing.

Later I restored my game, and noticed I didn't have a pistol equipped. I also still only have one in my pack, with no bullets in it. Somehow I lost the loaded pistol.

How could that have happened? Are there some pickpocket characters who can sometimes steal something from you? Or is there a bug with saved games that can remove something from your hand? I suppose it's possible I managed to leave it somewhere by UI accident, but I tried looking in the shelves, corpse, and shopkeepers I remembered visiting recently, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, kids in Den are pickpocketers. You can spot it happens around casino or weapon shop where they are standing on side of the door and doing this "hands moving" animation while your character standing nearby.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in some versions of the game, the kids are invisible. In versions where they do appear, they are killable, which would have gotten the game banned in several countries.

Comment: OMG! Wow, ok, cool. And, now I have a little more sympathy for the players who end up laying waste to towns... :-)  And, @Studoku LOL! Wow, that's classic! Invisible pickpocketing urchins! Are they immune to explosions too? ;-)